# what is the server operating system that runs intels website/s

Tags: web, operating-system, webserver, intel

i think the title tells all about what I wanted to ask here,
and in more details,

what server technology does Intel websites run on ?  was the question in title and in search box

what operating system , platform/language is being used (also what database is nice to know )

i would think they use Intel cpu's with Microsoft servers Os (might be kind of super OS)
and off course asp.net c# 
but running any variation of a search terms yield no results in Google.
i can understand google though (  it is still a machine and you can imagine what it is seeing when i type :

```
intel server operating system website .... 
or 
intel website operating system server version....
```

you could try anything you like .

play with /move/ add ... those words ... still the same if you are not human

really all i wanted to know is what i can guess you could understand from this title
but i don't blame google. nither the search engine SO is using ...

but i think i'm lucky we have you human real people @ SO here...

Comment: The server sends back some headers: `Server:IA Web Server` and `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=...`.

Comment: IA Web Server - gooogle = *(result #6) http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2005/12/28/79879.aspx

Comment: @Blender I was right didn't I, nice job ! oh i can't belive it (: 
all the talk about better open source stuff i allmost thought of dropping my studies in asp.net c# etc' but i think i really need to learn java (: